# RelatedRecordId is not showing in available fields on ServiceResource object

Tags: validation-rule, standard-objects

I need to make User field required on standard [ServiceResource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_serviceresource.htm) object.

[image]

I was thinking, that it should be a simple Validation Rule, which checks that this field is blank, but during the creation faced with the problem, that User field (API name RelatedRecordId) is not showing in the available fields:

[image]

Any ideas how to make this field required on insert, except trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from trigger, you can do this in layout.
[image]

And then only in UI this field will be required:

[image]